# How to make a single task into parallel thread

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I am having this piece of code to generate a picture of drawing, but I also try to implement this task by using thread.

Here is original code

public class Starter extends Application {

```
private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 700; 
private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
private static final int X_OFFSET = 25;
private static final int Y_OFFSET = 25;
private static double MANDELBROT_RE_MIN = -2;  
private static double MANDELBROT_RE_MAX = 1;       
private static double MANDELBROT_IM_MIN = -1.2;    
private static double MANDELBROT_IM_MAX = 1.2;      

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane fractalRootPane = new Pane();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

    paintSet(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(),
            MANDELBROT_RE_MIN,
            MANDELBROT_RE_MAX,
            MANDELBROT_IM_MIN,
            MANDELBROT_IM_MAX);

    fractalRootPane.getChildren().add(canvas);

    Scene scene = new Scene(fractalRootPane, CANVAS_WIDTH + 2 * X_OFFSET, CANVAS_HEIGHT + 2 * Y_OFFSET);
    scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Mandelbrot Set");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void paintSet(GraphicsContext ctx, double reMin, double reMax, double imMin, double imMax) {
    double precision = Math.max((reMax - reMin) / CANVAS_WIDTH, (imMax - imMin) / CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    int convergenceSteps = 50;
    for (double c = reMin, xR = 0; xR < CANVAS_WIDTH; c = c + precision, xR++) {
        for (double ci = imMin, yR = 0; yR < CANVAS_HEIGHT; ci = ci + precision, yR++) {
            double convergenceValue = checkConvergence(ci, c, convergenceSteps);
            double t1 = (double) convergenceValue / convergenceSteps;
            double c1 = Math.min(255 * 2 * t1, 255);
            double c2 = Math.max(255 * (2 * t1 - 1), 0);

            if (convergenceValue != convergenceSteps) {
                ctx.setFill(Color.color(c2 / 255.0, c1 / 255.0, c2 / 255.0));
            } else {
                ctx.setFill(Color.PURPLE); // Convergence Color
            }
            ctx.fillRect(xR, yR, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}

private int checkConvergence(double ci, double c, int convergenceSteps) {
    double z = 0;
    double zi = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < convergenceSteps; i++) {
        double ziT = 2 * (z * zi);
        double zT = z * z - (zi * zi);
        z = zT + c;
        zi = ziT + ci;

        if (z * z + zi * zi >= 4.0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return convergenceSteps;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Here is what I have altered into Thread class.

public class ThreadTest extends Thread {

```
// Size of the canvas for the Mandelbrot set
private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 700;
private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
// Left and right border
private static final int X_OFFSET = 25;
// Top and Bottom border
private static final int Y_OFFSET = 25;
// Values for the Mandelbro set
private static double MANDELBROT_RE_MIN = -2;
private static double MANDELBROT_RE_MAX = 1;
private static double MANDELBROT_IM_MIN = -1.2;
private static double MANDELBROT_IM_MAX = 1.2;
@Override
public void run(){
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Pane fractalRootPane = new Pane();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

    paintSet(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(),
            MANDELBROT_RE_MIN,
            MANDELBROT_RE_MAX,
            MANDELBROT_IM_MIN,
            MANDELBROT_IM_MAX);

    fractalRootPane.getChildren().add(canvas);

    Scene scene = new Scene(fractalRootPane, CANVAS_WIDTH + 2 * X_OFFSET, CANVAS_HEIGHT + 2 * Y_OFFSET);
    scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Mandelbrot Set");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}



private void paintSet(GraphicsContext ctx, double reMin, double reMax, double imMin, double imMax) {
    double precision = Math.max((reMax - reMin) / CANVAS_WIDTH, (imMax - imMin) / CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    int convergenceSteps = 50;
    for (double c = reMin, xR = 0; xR < CANVAS_WIDTH; c = c + precision, xR++) {
        for (double ci = imMin, yR = 0; yR < CANVAS_HEIGHT; ci = ci + precision, yR++) {
            double convergenceValue = checkConvergence(ci, c, convergenceSteps);
            double t1 = (double) convergenceValue / convergenceSteps;
            double c1 = Math.min(255 * 2 * t1, 255);
            double c2 = Math.max(255 * (2 * t1 - 1), 0);

            if (convergenceValue != convergenceSteps) {
                ctx.setFill(Color.color(c2 / 255.0, c1 / 255.0, c2 / 255.0));
            } else {
                ctx.setFill(Color.PURPLE); // Convergence Color
            }
            ctx.fillRect(xR, yR, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Checks the convergence of a coordinate (c, ci) The convergence factor
 * determines the color of the point.
 */
private int checkConvergence(double ci, double c, int convergenceSteps) {
    double z = 0;
    double zi = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < convergenceSteps; i++) {
        double ziT = 2 * (z * zi);
        double zT = z * z - (zi * zi);
        z = zT + c;
        zi = ziT + ci;

        if (z * z + zi * zi >= 4.0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return convergenceSteps;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadTest t1 = new ThreadTest();
    t1.start();
}
```

}

Is there are any better way to achieve this task into parallel mode?

Comment: Please try to reduce this to a [mcve]. Remember that nobody here is paid to read your code, to then deduce what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Also please explain what you want. Is the code not working correctly? If so, in what way? If your code does work and you just want feedback on it take a look at [codereview.se]